# meaning of "you admin"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is my conversation with my friend:

1. Me: Don't worry, I'll not let you down
2. My friend: ok my friend. I trust you, you admin.

I don't understand what `You admin` means.
How should i understand the meaning of `You admin`?

Comment: Were you by any chance chatting on WhatsApp?

Comment: Why don't you ask him?

Comment: I can't tell what your friend meant. Are you an admin, or are they an admin, on whatever you were using to chat?

Comment: I got it. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is incomplete and erroneous, at this point. Your friend might have meant *I trust you, you're the admin*, or something of that sort. Like the second comment under the question suggests, ask your friend.

Comment: Thanks for your help!